# Padding of Struct containing only structs

Tags: c++, c, struct, padding

Let`s say I have 2 structs:

```
struct Foo
{
    int size;  // 4
    int type;  // 4
    char data; // 1
};

static const struct Foo FooContainer[] = {
{1, 2, 3},
{4, 5, 6},
...
};
```

If I use something like:

```
int structsincontainer = sizeof(FooContainer) / sizeof(struct Foo);
```

Will I always get the correct number of structs in the container? I assume since the padding is already done in struct Foos the container will not need any padding?

Comment: "Let`s say I have 2 structs:" You don't. You have 1 struct and an array of struct. Not a "struct containing struct".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FooContainer` is an array. Arrays in both C and C++ are guaranteed to not add padding between their elements. Any padding that may be present is only that which is internal to the element object type itself.

So yes, the `sizeof` trick is a common technique that is guaranteed to work, so long as the parameter to `sizeof` is indeed the name of an array, and not a pointer that was obtained by an array-to-pointer conversion.

Having said all that, since you tagged C++, try to avoid raw arrays. The C++ standard library has several alternatives that provide greater safety and more functionality.

And even if you do use a raw array, a better way to obtain the size in C++ would be with the help of the type system itself:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto array_size(T(&)[N]) { return N; }
```

The above is very easy to use like so `int structsincontainer = array_size(FooContainer);` and will only accept an array reference, instead of silently building when passed a pointer by accident.

Comment: even better, there is a std::size for arrays and containers since c++17.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. The padding is already considered in `sizeof(struct foo)`.

In general, for any array `T arr[n];` (where `T` is any type), `sizeof arr == (n * sizeof(T))`. This is guaranteed by the language.